# Entity Framework using foreign key as only primary key in one to many

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework code first to design the database.

I have 2 models with One to Many relationship. One "Foo" can have many "FooData" as follows -

```
public class Foo {
  [Key]
  public string serialNumber{get; set;}
  public int someNumber {get; set;}
  public string someName {get; set;}
  // Many more properties
  // Navigation Collection
  public virtual ICollection<FooData> FooDatas{get; set;}
}

public class FooData{
  [Key]
  [ForeignKey("foo")]
  public string SerialNum {get; set;}
  public DateTime SomeTime {get; set;}
  public byte[] SomeData {get; set;}
  // Navigation property
  public virtual Foo foo {get; set;}
}
```

When I try to add a controller for "Foo" in MVC, using "Foo" as a scaffolding model, it gives me this error - "Multiplicity is not valid in Role. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be 1".

I would appreciate some help here.

Thank you

Comment: If `FooData.SerialNum` is the primary key for its `FooData`, and a foreign key in `Foo`, then the relationship between classes can't be 1-many, it is limited to 1-0:1 because making it `Key` forces it to be unique.  Try removing `Key` from `FooData.SerialNum`.

Comment: If I remove the [key] from FooData then the error says "FooData" has no key defined.

Comment: You will probably need to create surrogate identity key field for the detail table.

Comment: Yes, I believe that would be the solution. Thanks Bradley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how you have it defined the same key is used in both so it is a 1-to-1 relationship. If you want a real  one to many you will need to add/create another field and set them up as a composite key on the FooData table/entity.

```
public class Foo {
    [Key]
    public string serialNumber{get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<FooData> FooDatas{get; set;}
}

public class FooData {
  [Key, Column(Order = 0),ForeignKey("foo")]
  public string SerialNum {get; set;}
  [Key,Column(Order=1)]
  public int DataId {get;set;}
  public virtual Foo foo {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I did. Thanks.