# EF Core: The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Assume we have the two following database tables:

```
Foo:
> FooId (PK)
> FooName

Bar:
> BarId (PK, FK)
> Comment
> Other columns...
```

I have the following EF mapping:

```
[Table("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public long FooId { get; set; }

    public string FooName { get; set; }

    // (0-n) relation
    // public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

[Table("Bar")]
public class Bar
{
    // PK/FK
    [Key, ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public long BarId { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

The entity "Bar" has only a foreign key as primary key.
Whenever I try to insert new Bar entities like this:

```
var demoList = new List<Bar>();
// Populate demoList with random data
_context.Bars.AddRange(demoList);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
'The instance of entity type 'Bar' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'BarId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'
```

EF is considering that "BarId" must be unique as the property is marked as "Key", but it's a PK/FK in a one to many relation ("Foo" can have 0 or many "Bar"), what I'm missing here please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856073/the-instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-of-this-t)

Comment: If you try to create a short, self-contained repro using your Foo and Bar types you'll probably figure it out for yourself.  Otherwise post it as part of your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38231728/11814547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Foo` can have Zero or Many `Bar`s it is a One-To-Many relationship. You would typically create a key as both `PrimaryKey` and `ForiegnKey` if the relationship is One-to-Zero-or-One. So per your requirement you models should be more like below:

```
[Table("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public long FooId { get; set; }

    public string FooName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

[Table("Bar")]
public class Bar
{

    [Key]
    public long BarId { get; set; }

    public long FooId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FooId")]
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "BarId" is not relevant in "Bar" table, the "FooId" is already the PK/FK in the same table. A typical SQL query to get "Bar" list linked to "FooId" will be like: SELECT * FROM Bar WHERE FooId = 1. "BarId" will not be used anywhere.

Comment: @Karim why would you want to have FooId as both PK and FK? You would do that only when a Foo can have 0 or 1 Bar. But your requirement is a Foo may have 0 or many Bars

Comment: Yes you're right, I do need a BarId if I want to have a zero-to-many relationship